# BeautifulSoup not finding elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to write a program that extracts the prices of the below website. I'm downloading the site with selenium and then try to parse it either with beautifulsoup or with selenium itself.

I determined that the information I want is always class="totalPrice" and I would like to extract them all, ideally as a list.

```
<td class="totalPrice" colspan="3">
Total: £560
<span class="sr_room_reinforcement"></span>
</td>
```

For some reason the below queries never find any totalPrice. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url='http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaFCIAQGYAS64AQTIAQTYAQHoAQH4AQs;sid=1a43e0952558ac0ad0061d5b6523a7bc;dcid=1;checkin_monthday=4;checkin_year_month=2016-2;checkout_monthday=11;checkout_year_month=2016-2;city=-2601889;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;group_adults=7;group_children=0;highlighted_hotels=1192837;hp_sbox=1;label_click=undef;no_rooms=1;review_score_group=empty;room1=A%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA;sb_price_type=total;score_min=0;si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi;ss=London;ssafas=1;ssb=empty;ssne=London;ssne_untouched=London&;order=price_for_two'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# for elm in driver.find_element_by_class_name("totalPrice"):
#     print(elm.text)

content = driver.page_source
soup = bs(content, 'lxml')
for e in soup.find_all('totalPrice'):
    print(e.name)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to *wait when the total prices would be loaded*. Use [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) class with a `precense_of_element_located` Expected Condition.

I've also found out that you would need *to pretend not to be `PhantomJS`* by overriding the browser's `User-Agent` through the Desired Capabilities.

Complete working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaFCIAQGYAS64AQTIAQTYAQHoAQH4AQs;sid=1a43e0952558ac0ad0061d5b6523a7bc;dcid=1;checkin_monthday=4;checkin_year_month=2016-2;checkout_monthday=11;checkout_year_month=2016-2;city=-2601889;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;group_adults=7;group_children=0;highlighted_hotels=1192837;hp_sbox=1;label_click=undef;no_rooms=1;review_score_group=empty;room1=A%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA;sb_price_type=total;score_min=0;si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi;ss=London;ssafas=1;ssb=empty;ssne=London;ssne_untouched=London&;order=price_for_two'

# setting a custom User-Agent
user_agent = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) " +
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36"
)

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.get(url)

# wait for the total prices to become present
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".totalPrice")))

content = driver.page_source
driver.close()

soup = bs(content, 'lxml')
for e in soup.select('.totalPrice'):
    print(e.text.strip())
```

It prints:

```
Total: US$781
Total: US$814
Total: US$831
Total: US$864
Total: US$895
Total: US$914
Total: US$915
Total: US$967
Total: US$1,031
```

---

As a side note, you don't really need `BeautifulSoup` - you can [locate elements with `selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) - it is quite powerful. Here is how you can locate the total prices:

```
for price in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".totalPrice"):
    print(price.text.strip())
```